# How can I convert this javascript / jQuery into a "not inline" function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hvae the following code:

```
$(".openDialog").live("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $("<div></div>")
    .addClass("dialog")
    .attr("id", $(this).attr("data-dialog-id"))
    .appendTo("body")
    .dialog({
        title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
        close: function () { $(this).remove() },
        modal: true
    })
    .load(this.href);
});
$(".close").live("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest(".dialog").dialog("close");
});
```

Can someone explain how I can decouple the functions form the actions? I am a bit confused with how to do this.

Also what is the purpose of "live" ?   I heard before someone suggesting "on". Is "on" better than "live" and how does it actually work?

Comment: All functions in JavaScript as just values. Take `function callback () {};`: now, in the applicable scope, `callback` merely evaluates to said function-object.

Comment: as far as second part of the question is concerned live is deprecated `on` is included in the version 1.7+ if you dont have the latest version of jQuery then try using delegate, the purpose is to attach the event handlers to the dynamically added elements to the DOM...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just break the functions out, then pass the function name:

```
close: closeFunction    

function closeFunction() { 
   $(this).remove() 
}
```

---

```
$(".close").live("click", closeClick);

function closeClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest(".dialog").dialog("close");
}
```

---

`on` is indeed better than `live`.  Both allow you to wire up events to *dynamically added* content, but the former is more efficient, and the latter is deprecated, .  Here's how you'd use it

```
$(document).on("click", ".close", closeClick);
```

or, ideally, if all these `.close` buttons were to be in a container, say, a div with `id` foo, you could more efficiently do

```
$("#foo").on("click", ".close", closeClick);
```

or for jQuery pre 1.7 you'd have to settle for `delegate`

```
$("#foo").delegate(".close", "click", closeClick);
```

Answer (score 3):

> Also what is the purpose of "live" ? I heard before someone suggesting
>   "on". Is "on" better than "live" and how does it actually work?

Since jQuery 1.7 .live is deprecated: http://api.jquery.com/live/

> As of **jQuery 1.7**, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live().

More about new `.on()` feature: http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/03/jquery-1-7-released/